# How to save for loop output to a column in data frame

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

How would i save the output from this python script as a dataframe?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, SoupStrainer


response = requests.get('https://webscraper.io/test-sites/e-commerce/allinone')

for link in BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser", parse_only=SoupStrainer('a', href=True)):
    print(link['href'])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might consider putting your code into a function that returns the desired output

```
def myfunction(response = response, parser = "html.parser", ...):
    '''
    this function saves output
    '''
    ....     
     return(output)
```

or you could define a list and index over the loop

```
mylist = []

i = 1

for link in BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser", parse_only=SoupStrainer('a', href=True)):
    mylist[i] = link['href']
    i += 1
```

Without more detail about what it is exactly you're trying to do, it is difficult to provide more guidance

Comment: Thanks! Ended up using the list method to append each loop to the list and then turn the list into a dataframe.  Though your code didn't work the methodology did. I replaced the print statement with mylist.append((anchor['href']))